# lead and lag function on sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data pulled through the following query

```
Select *
FROM        
    (Select RP.ins_user_id, RP.Loadno, Max(RP.trndte) 'M1', Min(RP.trndte)'M2', sum(RP.trnqty) 'QTY'
                 from
                    (select R.ins_user_id,R.trnqty, R.trndte,
                        "Loadno" =
                            case when
                            R.actcod = 'sstg' then R.lodnum 
                            else R.to_lodnum
                        end
            from dbo.RP_DlyTrn R
            where R.oprcod IN ('LPCK', 'RLPCK') 
            and R.actcod in ('caspck', 'otrpck', 'palpck', 'pcepck','sstg', 'list-start')
            and R.ship_id <> 0
            and R.trndte between '08/18/2014 17:25:00' and '08/19/2014 8:00:00') RP
            where RP.Loadno is not null
            group by RP.ins_user_id, RP.Loadno) rp2
            order by RP2.ins_user_id, RP2.Loadno
```

Results:

```
ins_user_id  Loadno            end time(M1)       start time(M2)        qty   start_time suc load  
AMCPHEE   L00000971730  2014-08-19 07:59:30   2014-08-19 07:47:16   7           Null
CBOWLEG   L00000968872  2014-08-18 18:35:37   2014-08-18 18:22:50   29          Null
CBOWLEG   L00000968927  2014-08-18 18:43:03   2014-08-18 18:38:45   4    2014-08-18 18:45:55    
CBOWLEG   L00000968965  2014-08-18 18:52:20   2014-08-18 18:45:55   9    2014-08-18 18:54:50
CBOWLEG   L00000969024  2014-08-18 18:58:24   2014-08-18 18:54:50   3    2014-08-18 19:00:48
CBOWLEG   L00000969068  2014-08-18 19:16:23   2014-08-18 19:00:48   51   2014-08-18 19:00:48
CBOWLEG   L00000969170  2014-08-18 19:22:45   2014-08-18 19:19:45       7    2014-08-18 19:24:34
CBOWLEG   L00000969194  2014-08-18 20:07:41   2014-08-18 19:24:34   73
```

using the lag function I would like to get the start time of the succeeding load against each load for each user.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: What is the issue? Just apply the LEAD or LAG function to the same expression you are using to get the start time. Or is there more to this? As written, your problem seems to be a matter of direct application of the [manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx "LEAD (Transact-SQL)").